# How to send commend to device using QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, nmea

I am trying to use QSerialPort to get information from a sonar(EchoRange Smart Sensor), but I have no experience in this field. With the settings of portname, baudrate(4800,tested also others rates), databits(8bit),flowcontrol(no),parity(no) and stopbits(two), I can get the dataflow by :

> const QByteArray data=m_serialport->readAll();
>   qDebug()<< QString(data)

But the output is very strange.

> b'\x00\x00'
>   b'['
>   b'\xd7\xd7\xd7uu\xed\xedn-\xd9\x95\xeb\xb7'
>   b'YweWQ'
>   b'\xa7\x9b\x93\xa3\x8f'
>   b'\x8d\xa7y\xab\x99'
>   b'\x9d\xe5\xeb\x00'

But according the NMEA 0183 standard, I should get something like:

> $SDDPT,...

I wonder if I have to send to my device a command to tell it which data to emit.
So I tested

> m_serialport->write(QByteArray("$PAMTC,EN,ALL,1,5*hh"));
>
> m_serialport->write(QByteArray("$SDDPT"))
>
> m_serialport->write(QByteArray("$--DBT,x.x,f,x.x,M,x.x,F*hh"))

Nothing change, but the indicator light shows my device receive a signal.

Could you tell me how to get for example the Depth data in the protocol below?
Thank you in advance!
http://www.tronico.fi/OH6NT/docs/NMEA0183.pdf
[image]

Comment: What does the device documentation state about the serial communication settings? Have you looked at the data line using an oscilloscope?

Comment: Sorry, I have no oscilloscope. I just have two indicator lights to show the state of reception and emission.